# how does Collections.binarySearch() with comparator work when the input is not in sorted?

Tags: java, binary-search

I am confused that this method doesn't work as expected:

public static  int binarySearch(List list,
                   T key,
                   Comparator c)

here is my code

```
// Create a list 
    List<Domain> l = new ArrayList<Domain>(); 
    l.add(new Domain(10, "quiz.geeksforgeeks.org")); 
    l.add(new Domain(70, "practice.geeksforgeeks.org")); 
    l.add(new Domain(30, "code.geeksforgeeks.org")); 
    l.add(new Domain(40, "www.geeksforgeeks.org")); 
    l.add(new Domain(20, "practice.geeksforgeeks.org")); 
    l.add(new Domain(21, "practice.geeksforgeeks.org")); 



    // Searching a domain with key value 10. To search 
    // we create an object of domain with key 10. 
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(l, 
                             new Domain(31, null),new Comparator<Domain>() 
                             { 
                                 public int compare(Domain u1, Domain u2) 
                                 { 
                                     return u1.getId().compareTo(u2.getId()); 
                                 } 
                             }); 
    System.out.println("Found at index  " + index);
```

it returns -7 to me which is not correct.
From the documentation, it says "The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator". Here the sorted list should be :Domain(10...,20,21,30,40,70
I didnt see why the -7?

Comment: "The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator."  That's a prerequisite, not a statement of what it performs.

Answer (score 3):

The pre-condition of binary search is the input list needs to be sorted (regardless of default comparator or custom).

You can use `Collections.sort()` method (with default comparator or custom) to pre-sort your list.